# Visual studio pulling a cached page

Tags: asp.net

I think my visual studio is pulling a cached version of a webpage. See I am putting in code in the page, but when I run the website it never shows up.

And if I delete parts of the webpage, they still show when I run it.

I tried to rebuild but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is it definitely VS, not the browser? Have you tried clearing the cache in your browser? ctrl+f5 works as a force-refresh in some browsers, and there's usually extra ways to do this in your browser's debug tools.

Comment: You didn't say which web server you're using - the built-in one, IIS, or something else. Are you sure you're looking at the right page on the right server? Have you tried rebooting your machine so that the cache is cleared?

Comment: Tried both clear cache and restarting the machine. Yes I am looking at the correct page.

Comment: Is this a web application project, or a web site? Do you deploy it? If so, then how do you deploy?

Comment: I go to open ==> web site. It's running locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "putting code in the page," are you referring to the markup (aspx/ascx/cshtml/vbhtml/etc), or a code file (.cs, .vb)?

If you're modifying the code-behind file (webforms) or a controller (MVC), and you're (hopefully) using a web application project instead of a website project, you need to recompile the solution for your changes to take effect.